# javascript multiply input by number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple function for a table I have been tasked with creating. I want the user to enter a number into the first input field, and have that number be multiplied by 30, and have the result show in the second input field, by keyup or onChange.

Here's what I have so far, please keep in mind I'm very very new at this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Costs</td>
        <td>$
            <input type="text" id="daily">
        </td>
        <td>$
            <input type="text" id="result">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#daily').keyup(function () {
        var daily = $('#daily').val();
        var month = 30;
        $('#result').val(daily * month);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is your problem? Because when I enter '1' result says '30' and '12'->'360'. http://jsfiddle.net/xmGH4/, works fine here (on FF)

Comment: So, what's the question?  Does this work?  Not work?  What do you want from us?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Br92/ it works for me...

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: If you're just getting started don't get into the bad habit of using tables for layout purposes, Use CSS instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
   $('#daily').on('keyup', function (){
     var daily = parseInt($('#daily').val());
     var month = 30;
     $('#result').val(daily * month);
   });
});
```

I tried to use the ".on" binding instead of directly using ".keyup" because that could prevent errors if that table is a result of an ajax call

Comment: `parseInt` isn't the problem here.  There's an implicit cast when doing `*`.

Comment: Have you noticed the ".on('keyup')" binding instead of just ".keyup"?
if that doesn't work, it must be some external error. the code works fine on jsFiddle

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare

```
var daily = parseInt($('#daily').val());
```

Comment: There's an implicit cast when doing `*`.

Comment: And as various fiddle will show, it is working at this point. If you want to get uptight, you should use `parseInt('123', 10)`, note the 10 for decimal system :)